# How to disconnect an idle established connection without killing the related process? and tcpkill doesn't work

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, connection

There is an idle established connection on Linux with an remote server. Now need to kill it. But the process is not permitted to kill. Somebody said using `tcpkill`. But `tcpkill` depends on there is some transferring data.  Because java default disable the `socket keepalive` option, so there is not any data exchange, then `tcpkill` doesn't work. Finally,the connection will be alive for a day, a week, a year ... without any data packet transfer.

So anyboby have a method to disconnect or kill it? Thanks very much!

Comment: Java doesn't do anything to the default socket keepalive option. If it's off by default, Java leaves it that way. If it's on by default, ditto.

Comment: If linux have configed keepalive parameters. Java socket need to active it to use this feature. Jdk7.0 keepalive option:      * <p> The initial value of this socket option is {@code FALSE}. The socket
     * option may be enabled or disabled at any time.

Comment: That is correct. Where you were incorrect is that Java doesn't disable it. You have to enable it if it is off by default. If it is on by default Java leaves it that way.

Comment: The problem is i have no method to enable it. Because i am not permitted to kill the process. What i want to do is to kill the regular tcp connection without killing the related process.

Comment: You mean enable it externally to the process?

Comment: I want a method to kill the tcp connection without killing the related process.